# Using Sequence Generated ID or alternate way to query the DB

Tags: templates, primary-key, sequence, letter

We currently maintain a set of templates in the DB. In the application, we provide a droplist in the  UI to allow the user to select the template which they want to use to create a letter based on that template. So, we are showing the description of the template and when selected we pass the templateID to the DB to retrieve the template.

Now, we have a new requirement to generate a letter from a template without a UI to select the type of template. What I mean is , the particular point in the application from which the action is done by the user to invoke generate the letter itself serves to identify the particular template to use. So, my question is what do I pass to query the DB to return the stored template. I know I need to use the templateID. My Question  is this templateID is generated by a sequence every time the template is added to the system. So, only after this template has been added to the system, can I know the templateID and then use that templateID while invoking the action to generate the letter. So, that would mean a change after the template record is added to the system. That would involve a code change or if not a change in configuration file to map the sequence generated ID to the template as required  by the application.

So, my question is should I pass anotherIdentifier while invoking the letter generation and then have that identifier mapped to the Sequence generated one in the DB by having a configuration file and update this configuration file every time a new template is added to the system. Is there a better way for me to approach this issue.

Comment: I have decided to proceed as follows. Decide before the applicationID which would be used in the particular point in the application and add that applicationID itself as the templateID to the table in DB, instead of using a sequence to generate the templateID every time. So, applicationID would be unique and that would be added every time a template is added to the system. Since, it is already decided that can be directly used in the application without the need of any configuration file for mapping. Does this seem the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying that your system

- stores templates, and also
- lets users create templates at run time.

And you're having trouble deducing the template id number for the templates created at run time.  You seem to know the id numbers of existing templates.  (I could be wrong.)

Any dbms that lets you insert rows using a sequence generator, regardless of what that generator is called, will also provide a way for you to find out the last id number it gave you.  PostgreSQL is a common, open source dbms; it provides several such functions. One is nextval(), which increments the sequence and returns the new value. It's safe in a multi-user environment; it always returns *your* new value, not someone else's.

You'll need to check your dbms documentation to find out what functions it provides, and what their features and limitations are.

Comment: Yes. the system has an option to add new templates as well as allow the user to create letters from those templates. The user is shown the description of the templates, and after selection the id is passed to db to retrieve the template.    Now, its a different scenario. There is a page in the application through which a letter has to be created from a specific template. So,no need to show the option to select the template but directly pass the templateid.  Once the template is added to system, templateid is generated. At a time more than one template can also be added.This was my problem.